# Regex Grouping Stepped Explanation

Tags: javascript, regex, ecmascript-6, regex-group

```
let quotedText = /'([^']*)'/;
console.log(quotedText.exec("she said 'hello'"));
//["'hello'", "hello"]
```

> why does hello appear twice?

Comment: [The docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) explain that index `[0]` is "The full string of characters matched" an index `[1], ...[n]` is "The parenthesized substring matches, if any."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first element in the result is the full match, and the second element is the [first captured group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). Remove the parentheses `()` to get only one result.

```js
let quotedText = /'[^']*'/;
console.log(quotedText.exec("she said 'hello'"));
```

If you still want to keep the parentheses, you can use a non-capturing group as shown below:

```js
let quotedText = /'(?:[^']*)'/;
console.log(quotedText.exec("she said 'hello'"));
```